# Joining multiple tables from postgres to python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, postgresql

I am totally new to programming in any language, so please be understanding.

I am trying to join sql tables and convert it to a pandas dataframe. I've been able to convert one table into a dataframe, but not sure how to do it with multiple tables. There are libraries I am trying to learn that work better with python than with sql, so I need dataframes for that process.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT symbol.ticker,  daily_data.date_price, daily_data.adj_close_price
FROM symbol
INNER JOIN daily_data
ON symbol.id = daily_data.stock_id
```

[Output for SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzHjs.png)

This is the code I tried in pycharm:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(host= '', dbname='', password='', user='')

cur = conn.cursor()

sql = SELECT symbol.ticker,  daily_data.date_price, daily_data.adj_close_price
FROM symbol
INNER JOIN daily_data
ON symbol.id = daily_data.stock_id;


dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
df= pd.DataFrame(dat)
print(df)
```

There is a syntax error of invalid syntax at symbol.ticker.  I am not sure how to correct the error in python.

Comment: You need quotation marks  **sql = """SELECT symbol.ticker,  daily_data.date_price, daily_data.adj_close_price
FROM symbol
INNER JOIN daily_data
ON symbol.id = daily_data.stock_id;"""**

Comment: Thank You.  I thought adding """ would cause the code not to run, so I was using only 1 and that did not work.